# sql query using LIKE or MATCH

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of 13 columns , out of those i have 5 columns that contains let say string data or VARCHAR data.

Now i have a string let say "abc".

I want to write a sql query to get all the rows that have this "abc" string in those 5 columns. "abc" can be the data of the column of part of the data of the column.

I used `LIKE` function

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 OR col2 OR col3 OR col4 OR col5 LIKE '%abc%';
```

but it didnt worked n got back all the rows.

I dont know how use `MATCH` function either, I m nt good in sql. so can anyone help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify condition multiple times:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE col1 LIKE '%abc%'
 OR col2 LIKE '%abc%'
 OR col3 LIKE '%abc%'
 OR col4 LIKE '%abc%' 
 OR col5 LIKE '%abc%';
```

This will be really slow because you have multiple `OR` and non-SARGable condition.

Alternatively:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE CONCAT_WS('^', col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) LIKE '%abc%';
```

---

Using [`MATCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) (preferred solution that utilizes full-text index):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE MATCH(col1, col2,col3,col4, col5) AGAINST ('abc');
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/254c63/1/0)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that to use `MATCH` you need to create index first:

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD FULLTEXT ft_index_name (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5);
```

Comment: Yup it worked thanks , can you also tell me what does MATCH do ?

Comment: @luck MATCH is for searching expression using full-text index. It is special index for quick searching faster than `LIKE '%abc%'`

Comment: #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list                                     i got this error for match query.   i am using phpmyadmin for sql database.    does it means match will not wotk on it

Comment: @luck You need first create it for these columns

Comment: @tad2025 how can i create that ?

Comment: @luck I strongly recommend to read documentation about full-text index. Remember this is SO, you will get solid starting point but not production-ready solution which you just copy and paste.